# MySQL 5.6 backup to MySQL 5.7... what to do

Tags: mysql

I just changed my db server, and I managed to import a db dump to the new system.
What troubles me is that, once done, I noticed I have now MySQL 5.7.32, while the previous database server was 5.6.48.

I checked the project from the browser and so far it seems to work as expected, without errors.

Should I care about this? Was I supposed to somehow migrate the dump before actually load it?
I searched Craft CMS docs but I did not find any detail on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fine. An export and subsequent import would have highlighted any incompatibilities.
Different story going to MySQL 8 though, that was a whole world of pain last time I tried it. Yii may have been updated since then, though.